# Is it possible to retrieve MUI column Display Names through SharePoint 2010 Web Service API?

Tags: web-services, localization, multilingual, mui

I have been trying to find information regarding retrieving MUI column Display Names and List Display names for different languages on a site where I have done MUI translations on. Using SharePoints 2010's web services.

I found this post doing it with PowerShell [Language dependant fields](http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2011/08/11/getting-and-setting-language-dependent-field-titles-using-powershell/) however i would like to do it through the Web Services. Is it possible to do with Web Services or should i use CSOM or something else to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It was not possible to do through SharePoint 2010's web services.
I ended up creating a small windows app to do extract this information.